# añadir mas acciones a las rutas - Laravel

Tags: laravel

Estoy tratando de cargar varios archivos a la vez a través de un botón y quisiera preguntarles si es posible hacer lo que he pensado o si existe otra manera.

Los archivos no es que se suban, si no que se leen y se guardan en una tabla en la bd, mediante lavaravel excel

Al intentar subir solo uno mi solucion fue la siguiente en la ruta:

```
Route::get('transpor', 'TransporController@store');
```

Pero no se como hacerlo para mas archivos, me pregunto si es posible hacer algo como esto:

```
 Route::get('transpor', ['TransporController@store', 'OtroController@store', OtroController@store']);
```

Ya que he visto la documentación pero solo veo agrupaciones de otro tipo

Comment: ¿Con qué fin llamar a varios controladores al tiempo?

Comment: Porque cada "archivo" tiene su propio tabla-modelo-controlador, y en cada controlador esta su método store

Comment: Si lo que deseas es corregir el método al que apuntas lo puedes hacer con un middleware. Pero como te comentan eso no tiene sentido. Si ya tienes la lógica para guardar uno. Haz la lógica para recibir uno o varios y de ahí mandas a llamar tu metodo para guardar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agregar más acciones a una ruta, iría en contra de algunos principios de programación, por lo cual es considerado una muy mala práctica.

Ese trabajo, de «delegar» las tareas a los componentes encargados, es precisamente lo que hace un controlador, por lo cual, en tu acción debería estar definido un método que llame a los actores necesarios para procesar la información que recibes, y obtener el resultado deseado. De antemano te digo, que es mála práctica también, llamar a otros controladores desde un controlador.

Ruta:

```
Route::get('transpor', 'TransporController@readAndStoreFiles');
```

Controlador:

```
public function readAndStoreFiles(Request $request)
{
    // llamar acción 1

    // llamar acción 2

    // llamar acción 3
}
```

Comment: comprendo, gracias por la respuesta, trataré de implementarla y veré si me funciona para marcarla como aceptada